# Boot 32-bit OS from 64-bit GRUB2

Tags: grub2

I can't believe nobody has asked this already, but...

If I've installed a 64-bit version of GRUB v2, is it supposed to be possible to load a 32-bit Linux kernel? Or will it only load a 64-bit one?

Is this something that's supposed to work? Or is this effort doomed to failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GRUB certainly doesn't care if your kernel is 64-bit or 32-bit. It just boot the kernel found in the path. If you have problems with GRUB they are not because the architecture which was built GRUB or the kernel.

Here a list of [supported kernels](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Supported-kernels) or boot targets.